# JQUERY Random Multiple quotes rotator need tweaking

Tags: jquery, quotes, rotator

I'm struggling trying to make my multiple quote rotator working.

I have a JS fiddle up and running [Jsfiddle - Multiple Quote Rotator](http://jsfiddle.net/2hPJY/8/)

```
jQuery(function(){
var quotes1 = [
[ '75', 'Happy Clients' ],
[ '25', 'Emails Typed a day' ],
];

var quotes2 = [
[ '14', 'Coffes a day' ],
[ '1', 'Squeacky Chair' ],
];
var quotes3 = [
[ '70', 'Phone Calls / Day' ],
[ '5', 'Spiders' ],
];
var quotes4 = [
[ '1000', 'Types on the keyboard' ],
[ '100%', 'Qualified Personel' ],
];
var quotes5 = [
[ '55', 'Planes' ],
[ '500', 'Girls' ],
];
var quotes6 = [
[ '160', 'Seo Campaigns running' ],
[ '1', 'Squeacky Chair' ],
];

$('.circle.one').loadText( quotes1, 200); 
$('.circle.two').loadText( quotes2, 400 ); 
$('.circle.three').loadText( quotes3, 600 ); 
$('.circle.four').loadText( quotes4, 800 ); 
$('.circle.five').loadText( quotes5, 1000 ); 
$('.circle.six').loadText( quotes6, 1200 );
});

$.fn.loadText = function( quotes, interval ) {
return this.each( function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var quote = random_array( quotes );
    var delaytest = delaytest;
    var quote_text = '<p class="facts_h1">' + quote[[0],[0]] + '</p>' + '<p   class="facts_p">' + quote[[0],[1]] + '</p>';

    obj.parent().fadeOut( 'linear', function() { 
            obj.empty().html(quote_text );  
            obj.parent().fadeIn(500);
    });

    $("#quote-reload").click( function(){ 
            if( !obj.is(':animated') ) { 
                obj.loadText( quotes, interval );
           } 
    });
});
 }
 function random_array( aArray ) {
    var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * aArray.length + aArray.length );
    var randArray = aArray[ rand - aArray.length ];
    return randArray;
 }
```

My problem is that I would like my 6 quotes to appear **one after the other** with an animation.

All I can manage is a global fade in fade out...

Am I making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I can manage is a global fade in fade out...

That's because you're applying the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to the `parent()` container of all the the `.circle` elements. Apply the fade animations to the objects themselves. See the following fiddle for more details:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DFfr/

Additionally:

1. Use `delay()` to stagger animations.
2. Use `fadeTo()` instead of `fadeIn/fadeOut` - `fadeTo()` animates the opacity only, while `fadeIn/fadeOut` will also hide the elements, resulting in element position jitter.

Comment: Hello Lee, Thanks for your reply. Thanks for your tips about fadeTo. It's getting close to what i wanted, and i'm getting better at this slowly.
  
[http://jsfiddle.net/6DFfr/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/6DFfr/14/)
  
My main concern now is that it is very buggy on my website, althought is that on my website, it works well at first but the more i click the more it lags....

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a function applied to each of them, have one function that works on a list of elements.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693418/jquery-calling-multiple-animations-in-a-row-on-click) for a demonstration on how to do that.